# Android Listview Table with fixed headers

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I need a table with fixed header. It is populated by 100-200 entries
I ran into problem with performance - 100+ rows are rendered very slowly.

There is a similar question already answered - [Android TableLayout with over 1000 rows loading very slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539559/android-tablelayout-with-over-1000-rows-loading-very-slowly)

It is suggested that Listview is used.

But the problem is, i cant find a way to make a Listview table with fixed and properly aligned header. Is there any way to make a fixed header with all columns equal in width?

edit: The top row needs to be always on top of the page, with the column names properly aligned to the main table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends, do you need the header to be able to scroll as well ? Or does it need to be always visible ?

- Needs to scroll : use [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean))
- Does not need to scroll : add a View over your ListView

The HeaderView will have a layout similar to your cells (to have the same column widths)

Answer (score 0):

I understant you want a fixed view with above your `ListView`. It is possible using `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:width="fill_parent"
      android:height="fill_parent"
      />
      <!-- the header -->
      <LinearLayout 
           android:id="@+id/header"
           android:width="fill_parent"
           android:height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:weightSum="4"
           >
           <TextView
                android:width="0dip"
                android:height="wrap_content"
                android:text="case 1"
                android:weight="1"
                />
           <TextView
                android:width="0dip"
                android:height="wrap_content"
                android:text="case 2"
                android:weight="1"
                />
           <TextView
                android:width="0dip"
                android:height="wrap_content"
                android:text="case 3"
                android:weight="1"
                />
           <TextView
                android:width="0dip"
                android:height="wrap_content"
                android:text="case 4"
                android:weight="1"
                />
       </LinearLayout>
       <ListView
            android:width="fill_parent"
            android:height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header"
            />
   </RelativeLayout>
```